# Unexpected Token error in Vue Package

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm installing a custom `vue` package on my project. Upon building it, I got the following error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/components/devices/domain/DeviceLocation/DeviceLocation.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:7)

  1 | export default class DeviceLocation {

> 2 |   name = ''
    |        ^
  3 |   identifier = ''
  4 |
  5 |   constructor (data) {
```

Seems like it's because of `=` instead of `:`

**DeviceLocation.js** file

```
export default class DeviceLocation {
  name = ''
  identifier = ''

  constructor (data) {
    Object.assign(this, data)
  }
}
```

Is there any webpack configuration or something that I should do to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you show `DeviceLocation`?  Did you write that class or is it a dependency?  Are you writing in TypeScript or JavaScript?  Because this looks vaguely like TypeScript member definitions (but still wrong since it's `=`).

Comment: One of my colleagues wrote this. Not a dependency. I'll update the question with part of the DeviceLocation. I don't think it's TypeScript, since the extension is `.js`

Comment: I would confirm with your colleague that this works and that they didn't commit untested code.

Comment: Yeah he said it works. It is so weird! Would this be some sort of webpack config + some loaders?

Comment: This would very likely be some kind of configuration on your colleague's end, though I don't have an answer regarding what that might be. The problem is that a standard JSON format is expected, but what you've shown here is NOT valid JSON. You should review your colleague's setup and see what his build process is, then compare it to yours in order to determine where the difference lies. In any case, your colleague is using a non-standard setup which potentially breaks everyone else's, so unless your other colleagues are using the same setup, he's objectively in the wrong here.

Comment: Barring differences in software being used and build process, you can also look into any configuration files or software version differences. Those alone can make a world of difference. If it turns out that he's using deprecated syntax support, or newly supported syntax, then only checking the software versions could make that clear.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check with his build setup

Answer (score 0):

As I know [class public fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields) is not available by default in projects generated by `vue-cli`. You should add babel plugin to make it work.

1) **Install plugin**:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

2) **Update  babel's config** (`.babelrc` file). 
You should add `transform-class-properties` to the list of existing plugin. For example:

```
# before
"plugins": ["transform-runtime"]

# after
"plugins": ["transform-runtime", "transform-class-properties"]
```

Read more about *Class public/private fiels* [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields) and about appropriate babel configuration [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)